# Android - stretching effect when rendering webview

Tags: android, android-webview, text-formatting

I want to show elements with formatted texts (bold and lists). For this I am using a Recyclerview with items that contain a Webview.

The content of the Webview is set as follows

```
String content = ...;
final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setDefaultFontSize( 14);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

At the time of loading the activity, the WebView generates a visual effect that makes it look ugly.

It is as if the webview starts with height 0, and then it is stretched and the content appears.
The same effect happens if I put the webview in an empty actiity.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: webSettings.setDefaultFontSize( 14); please don't use this line... and check..

Comment: @Relsell yes, without the line the effect is the same I added it later.

Comment: ok try adding your xml layout where you have added ... webview

Comment: You can add a splash layout before webview load finish.

Answer (score 1):

Add imageView into your Layout and override onPageFinished() in WebviewClient:

```
webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Image will be show before webview load finish.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it's not what I want.
I already have the text.
Why should I show a splash?